# Connecting a coin receptor to a key press

Tags: input, hardware, keyboard

I want to connect a coin receptor to a keyboard press.

I want to have an arcade cabinet with my computer game running. It should only add credits when a specific key is pressed, which can be triggered by the coin receptor.

I'm thinking the coin receptor would trigger a button press via an arm, or through a USB keyboard.

What kind of receptor do I need to make this happen?

I apologise if this is off-topic, I couldn't find a better hardware focused SE.

Comment: Look up "microswitch," I think, it you want to make your own. Or just "coin acceptor," to buy.

Comment: @jonk you are missing the point.... how does the micro-switch hit the F5 key... This is an X-Y problem.

Comment: @Trevor Well then, the OP needs a microswitch *and* a cheap $10 USB pluggable microcontroller development stick (and a few lines of C code -- for the micro and for the PC.) ;)

Comment: Eh, the PC doesn't need any code as long as the HID descriptor is done properly; it can be programmed to send any keypress required.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams which is great as long as Microsoft does not pop up a "Do you want to update Windows now?" dialog ;)

Comment: If the designer wants to build it around Windows then who are we to say that they're wrong 

Comment: @Trevor With Windows 10, if you answer "no" to that it will still just shut the machine down and update itself as soon as it feels you've walked away long enough.

Comment: @jonk LOL yup.. I noticed.

Comment: @Trevor You can buy the Enterprise LTSB version of the O/S. Those users are running "large collections" of Windows machines through an IT department or medical equipment, point-of-sale systems, or ATMs, which requires absolute rigid control. In this case, memory serving, you are permitted to control things again. I guess Microsoft wasn't powerful enough to force all medical devices to get automatically updated the moment they connected to the internet. ;)

Comment: My game runs on Windows, Mac and Linux. @jonk so I would program the microswitch to talk to the USB keyboard? What C code would I need on the PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things needed:

1. Cheap keyboard
2. Coin validator that can do pulse mode like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11636)
3. Low current relay, same voltage rating as the coin validator like [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/comus-international/3570-1210-123/1835-1085-ND/7497091)
4. Power supply for the coin validator and relay
5. Multimeter , wires , soldering station and also some soldering skills

Read the coin acceptor data sheet carefully and make the connections to the power supply.

Use counter output schematic to connect the relay coil to the coin validator, read the relay data sheet because this one already has an internal diode.

Dissasemble the keyboard and , using the multimeter, find the two pads on the control board connected to the key you need. If you cannot solder on them then take a different keyboard. Connect with wires the two pads to the relay contacts. To spare some space you can leave any other keyboard part and keep only the cable and the control board.

See [here](http://hackedgadgets.com/2010/05/10/computer-keyboard-disassembly-and-cleaning/) a video of a disassembled keyboard where the control board has large pads to solder on.

Power on all and, using the coin validator datasheet, set the press time to 100ms, counter/serial mode.

Ready to use